# Hibernate LAZY loading and spring's UserDetails

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have a stateless REST backend. So no HTML views. Just JSON and REST endpoints.
Authentication is done with Json Web Tokens. The client sends a JWT in each request.
My backend takes the user's email from the subject claim in this JWT. Then it loads the UserModel from the database in `class LiquidoUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService { ...}`

Each user is part of a team. But the Team is a big entity with a lot of information in it. So teams are only loaded lazily, when necessary:

*UserModel.java*

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class UserModel extends BaseModel {
  @NotNull
  @NonNull
  @Column(unique = true)
  public String email;
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)  // only load team info (with all info) if required
  public TeamModel team;

  [...]
}
```

Now I have a service that should return the team of the current user:

*TeamService.java*

```java
@PreAuthorize(HAS_ROLE_USER)
@RequestMapping("/getOwnTeam")
@Transactional                          // [1] 
public TeamModel getOwnTeam() {
  // Get currently logged in user (that was loaded with info from JWT)
  Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
  LiquidoAuthUser authUser = (LiquidoAuthUser)authentication.getPrincipal();
  // LiquidoAuthUser is the Adapter betwen spring's User and my USerModel
  UserModel currentUser = authUser.getLiquidoUserModel()    

  TeamModel team = currentUser.getTeam()     // <=== [2] throws LazyInitializationException

  return team
}
```

Now I think I know where the problem is. But I do not yet have a clean solution for it.

My UserModel is loaded in `class LiquidoUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService` But this happens very early, in a filter, when the HTTP request is processed. As it seams the `@Transaction` in my `TeamService` class is not yet started at that time.

Then when the code enters the `getOwnTeam()` method, a *new* transaction is started [1]. But in there I cannot lazy load the user's team anymore. [2]

**How can I model my users and teams, so that**

1. **The team data is only loaded when necessary**
2. **I *can* load the data manually when neccessary**

Comment: Can you confirm that TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive() is returning true within the @Transactional block?

Comment: Also, is there a reason for you to use @Transactional annotation with that method? I believe it's not necessary

Comment: The `@Transactional` annotation on the REST controller method `getOwnTeam()` was there, because I thought, then the UserModel **and** the lazy loaded TeamModel would be part of that one tansaction. Obviously that assumption was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need different load startegy you can use:

1. Native sql when query
2. jpql with construction like join fetch
3. Entity Graph (https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-entity-graph)
   The main benefit when you use such way to load is single request to database.
   You can read more https://thorben-janssen.com/lazyinitializationexception/

Your object in deatached state - this is reason of LazyInitializationException (you cat move it to other state to load your object)
for example

```
entityManager.merge(deatachedEntity);
```

Comment: I tried the merge aproach. But I get an error:  `entityManager.merge(currentUser);`   throws "could not initialize proxy [org.doogie.liquido.model.TeamModel#22] - no Session" -  I did keep the `@Transactional` annotation on the method.  Can you help?

Comment: aaaaahhhh. I found the solution.    The entityManager.merge(userModel) call **returns** the then merged/attached entity.   Once I use the **returned** value it works.  `currentUser = entityManager.merge(currentUser);`